# Pagination in RecyclerView when nestedScrollingEnabled is false

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. It is inside a `NestedScollView` and scrolls vertically. If I put `nestedScollingEnabled="true"`, then I can do pagination when the last element of `recyclerView` comes into view. But this way, the scrolling is very slow and it gets stuck a lot and feels very jittery.

When I put `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`, the scrolling is smooth, but I only get elements of the first API call and the pagination doesn't work.

I want to be able to paginate the contents of `recyclerView` and still be able to achieve a smooth scroll. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Check this [project](https://github.com/Mahendran-Sakkarai/Testing-Android-Applications/tree/stackoverflow-42158044) which i used same as yours with `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` and Its working fine for me. Instead of API I used a `Asynctask` to update the values. Check that and let me know or if you found the answer please post it.